# Event handler & background worker error in C#

Tags: c#, class, backgroundworker, visual-studio-2012

I'm a bit new to C# and I'm writing a proof of concept client/server application. Right now I'm trying to use a background worker to update a listbox from a class. This way I can provide basic logging. I understand just using a listbox is not optimal.

I've added an eventhandler to my class based on this code:
[BackgroundWorker report progress from external Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700348/backgroundworker-report-progress-from-external-class)

However I'm getting the following error:
Cannot assign to 'ReportProgress' because it is a 'method group'

I've tried to cut down my code to only show relevant parts. Also I have not completely implemented the code from the previous class, I just want to know what I'm missing that is causing the error. I feel like it's probably something simple.

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace V12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    //Background Workers
    private BackgroundWorker serverWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Server Backgroundworker
        serverWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        serverWorker.ReportProgress += new EventHandler<Server.ProgressArgs>(serverWorker_ReportProgress); //Error on this line
        serverWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(serverWorker_DoWork);
    }

private void serverWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //my work is here

    }
    protected void serverWorker_ReportProgress(object sender, Server.ProgressArgs e)
    {
        serverWorker.ReportProgress(e.Percentage, e.Message);
    }
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
namespace V12
{
public sealed class Server
{
    //Allows for updating of control on the UI Thread
    public EventHandler<ProgressArgs> ReportProgress;
    // Eventargs to contain information to send to the subscriber
    public class ProgressArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Percentage { get; set; }
        public object Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @esskar & SLaks for the quick replies. Is it possible for you to check the code on the stackoverflow page I referenced? 

I almost directly copied them and assumed the code worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you confused yourself. `ReportProgress` is not an event delegate, but a method.
Have a look at [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx). I think it is the handler you are looking for.

Comment: it seems the original code i was looking is invalid. i ended up using progresschanged as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

`ReportProgress` is a method.

You're trying to add a handler to the **`ProgressReported`** event.

Answer (score 0):

See if this provides the clues you need...

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
 {
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        Server server;

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            server = new Server();

            BackgroundWorker wrkr = new BackgroundWorker();
            wrkr.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            wrkr.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(wrkr_RunWorkerCompleted);
            wrkr.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(wrkr_ProgressChanged);
            wrkr.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(wrkr_DoWork);
        }

        void wrkr_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // do work...perhaps you might be incrementing a progress meter...
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(i,"Some message...");
            }

            e.Result = "some result...";
        }

        void wrkr_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // here you can use e.ProgressPercentage and e.UserState
            // to change the state of something on the thread the worker was created on...
            server.Percentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
            server.Message = e.UserState.ToString();
        }

        void wrkr_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // here you can do some final stuff. clean-up etc.
            server.Percentage = 100;
            server.Message = e.Result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```